# spark generic dataframe to dataSet type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics

Spark internally represents `DataFrame` as `Dataset[Row]`.
Now I have to types:

```
SparkDatasetProvider[T <: Product, C <: BaseConfiguration]
SparkDataFrameProvider[C <: BaseConfiguration]
    extends SparkDatasetProvider[Row, C]
```

I.e. I want to ensure that case classes for `Dataset[T]` and regular `Row` are supported.
How can I fix the:

```
type arguments [org.apache.spark.sql.Row,C] do not conform to trait SparkDatasetProvider's type parameter bounds
```

As I am not aware of a super class which combines `Row` and regular `case classes`.

## edit

```
trait SparkDatasetProvider[T <: Encoder[T]] {

  def provide(spark: SparkSession): Dataset[T]

}
trait SparkDataFrameProvider extends SparkDatasetProvider[Row, C] {

  override def provide(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame

}

object FooProvider extends SparkDataFrameProvider{
  override def provide(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = null
}

final case class FooFeed(foo:Int, bar:String)
object FooProviderC extends SparkDatasetProvider[FooFeed]{
  override def provide(spark: SparkSession): Dataset[FooFeed] = null
}

type parameter bounds [T <: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T]]
object FooProviderC extends SparkDatasetProvider[FooFeed]{
```

Following the suggestion - however, I cant get it to work.

Comment: I think you may use `[T: Encoder]` instead, since what Spark really need under the hood is an `Encoder`.

Comment: Why would you expect it work? `Row` is not `Product` so `extends SparkDatasetProvider[Row, C]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Exactly - I was not aware that there is a common super type of Encoder.

Comment: @user6910411 please see the edit. I still get the same compile error for `Encoder[T]`.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Now the number of type parameters won't match so your edit shouldn't give the same error.

Comment: I think, I can‘t see the error. Could you explain me where I am missing an additional parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to:

```
trait SparkDatasetProvider[T, C <: BaseConfiguration] {

  def provide(spark: SparkSession, c: C): Dataset[T]

}
trait SparkDataFrameProvider[C <: BaseConfiguration] extends SparkDatasetProvider[Row, C] {
  def provide(spark: SparkSession, c: C): DataFrame

}
```

i.e. to drop `Product`.